# Mezzanine: where is the database created by `manage.py createdb`

Tags: django, django-south, mezzanine

I have the following database settings in Mezzanine:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'lucidDB',
        'USER': 'lucid',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxxxx',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

I run the command `python manage.py createdb` and then answer `yes` to the question `Would you like to fake initial migrations? (yes/no):`.

Note: `south` was installed.

My questions:

1. I checked in postgres (postgres@ psql  --> postgres=# \l), but didn't find the database `lucidDB`. However, the system runs OK. Where exactly is the database created?
2. What does it mean by *fake* migration?
3. I didn't run `syncdb` or `makemigrations --> migrate` yet, why the system worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You didn't find the LucidDB in postgres because it wasn't created, you need to create it with the postgres shell see [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn#step-seven-configure-postgresql) for detailed description.
2. Faking a migration is marking it as complete without actually changing the database schema, it will simply add an entry in the migrationhistory database, see detailed description [here](http://www.djangopro.com/2011/01/django-database-migration-tool-south-explained/).
3. On the Mezzanine docs it is stated that createdb is a shortcut for syncdb and migrate commands, see [here](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/overview.html#installation) for detailed description.

Hope this helps!